What would happen, if I combined two photon beams with their electrical field components in phase, but their magnetic ones out of phase
I know very little physics, but was asking questions of an LLM to try to understand the nature of photons.  This lead a thought experiment set up like this.
I have a laser source, firing into a beam splitter.  One beam I take on a path that when I recombine the beams has them 180degrees out of phase.
The LLM said that the energy would be reflected back since after the splitter the electromagnetic flux would be 0 as the beams destructively interfered.  I understood this, like holding a rope fixed at one point and sending a wave down it, would reflect that wave back.
I also asked about if the phase of the electric and magnetic components of a photon could be manipulated independently, to which it said yes.
So if I recombined the two beams when the electric fields were 180degrees out of phase, but the magnetic fields were not... or visa versa, what would happen?
The LLM had no idea.  Does anyone?  Is this even possible?

Why the downvote? I'd like to understand the physics of something  Have I phrased it incorrectly?

The downvote is probably related to the use of LLM. Many questions on this site lately are of the form "please clean up this misunderstanding I got from reading generated nonsense" unfortunately.

If you condense and rephrase the question, leaving put the LLM stuff, you may get a good answer. I like the question.

What is an LLM? In light magnetic and electric fields are always in the same phase. you can not "manipulate" it.

@trula, "LLM" means, "Large Language Model." It's the generic name for ChatGPT-style AIs.

I know that LLM's are not a reliable source of information, hence my asking here.
I now see the issue as @trula indicated, you cannot manipulate the phase of one of the fields relative to the other.  Thank you for the answers!

The emission of photons is random and the sum of photons in the beam has no wave character with its minima and maxima of intensity. (Only in a radio wave do you get a wavy intensity of EM radiation). What you get at the beam splitter are polarized partial waves. However, the problem remains that the spatial intensity curve of each photon (its magnetic as well as its electric component) is randomly distributed. The maximum you get after merging the two partial beams is the “ bundling” of a photon pair by means of the joint oscillation of the magnetic dipoles.
